# Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.security.IKeystoreService.del(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore, huawei-mobile-services

I'm facing some issue in `KeyStore` implementation in only Huawei devices (Specially in Huawei Mate 9) other device working perfectly.

Error Log :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.security.IKeystoreService.del(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
       at android.security.KeyStore.delete(KeyStore.java:186)
       at android.security.Credentials.deletePrivateKeyTypeForAlias(Credentials.java:292)
       at android.security.Credentials.deleteAllTypesForAlias(Credentials.java:251)
       at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:464)
       at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:699)
       at com.example.utility.crypto.KeyStoreHelper.createKeys(Unknown Source)
       at com.example.utility.crypto.KeyStoreHelper.createKeys(Unknown Source)
       at com.example.activities.register.SplashActivity$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:255)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

Below KeyStoreHelper file

```
public class KeyStoreHelper {

    public static final String TAG = "KeyStoreHelper";

    /**
     * Creates a public and private key and stores it using the Android Key
     * Store, so that only this application will be able to access the keys.
     */
    public static void createKeys(Context context, String alias) throws NoSuchProviderException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        if (!isSigningKey(alias)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                createKeysM(alias, false);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                createKeysJBMR2(context, alias);
            }
        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    static void createKeysJBMR2(Context context, String alias) throws NoSuchProviderException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

        Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
        Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar();
        end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 30);

        KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                // You'll use the alias later to retrieve the key. It's a key
                // for the key!
                .setAlias(alias)
                .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(alias.hashCode())))
                // Date range of validity for the generated pair.
                .setStartDate(start.getTime()).setEndDate(end.getTime())
                .build();

        KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                SecurityConstants.TYPE_RSA,
                SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
        kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
        KeyPair kp = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Log.d(TAG, "Public Key is: " + kp.getPublic().toString());

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    static void createKeysM(String alias, boolean requireAuth) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                            alias,KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, F4))
                            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                            // Only permit the private key to be used if the user authenticated
                            // within the last five minutes.
                            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(requireAuth)
                            .build());
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            Log.d(TAG, "Public Key is: " + keyPair.getPublic().toString());

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * JBMR2+ If Key with the default alias exists, returns true, else false.
     * on pre-JBMR2 returns true always.
     */
    public static boolean isSigningKey(String alias) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            try {
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
                keyStore.load(null);
                return keyStore.containsAlias(alias);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the private key signature on JBMR2+ or else null.
     */
    public static String getSigningKey(String alias) throws CertificateEncodingException {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            Certificate cert = getPrivateKeyEntry(alias).getCertificate();
            if (cert == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return Base64.encodeToString(cert.getEncoded(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry getPrivateKeyEntry(String alias) {
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore
                    .getInstance(KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE);
            ks.load(null);
            KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry(alias, null);

            if (entry == null) {
                LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "No key found under alias: " + alias);
                LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Exiting signData()...");
                return null;
            }

            if (!(entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)) {
                LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Not an instance of a PrivateKeyEntry");
                LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Exiting signData()...");
                return null;
            }
            return (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String alias, String plaintext) {
        try {
            PublicKey publicKey = getPrivateKeyEntry(alias).getCertificate().getPublicKey();
            Cipher cipher = getCipher();
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes()), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(String alias, String ciphertext) {
        try {
            PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKeyEntry(alias).getPrivateKey();
            Cipher cipher = getCipher();
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(ciphertext, Base64.NO_WRAP)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static Cipher getCipher() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return Cipher.getInstance(
                String.format("%s/%s/%s",
                        SecurityConstants.TYPE_RSA,
                        SecurityConstants.BLOCKING_MODE,
                        SecurityConstants.PADDING_TYPE));
    }


    public interface SecurityConstants {
        String KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
        String TYPE_RSA = "RSA";
        String PADDING_TYPE = "PKCS1Padding";
        String BLOCKING_MODE = "NONE";

        String SIGNATURE_SHA256withRSA = "SHA256withRSA";
        String SIGNATURE_SHA512withRSA = "SHA512withRSA";

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Have you found solution to the problem?

Comment: No, still issue occur